# Why is the response I am receiving from my request not filtering correctly?

Tags: php, wordpress, api, solr, request

Good day,

I am trying to integrate an `API` into a `Wordpress` site.

[API Documentation](https://api.vincere.io/documentation.html#tag/search)

I have tested the `AP`I using `Postman` and I am able to get the correct response.

Reading the documentation and various other sources I have come up with the following code to list the various results and then perform a search on the results.

```
public function search_jobs( $param = [], $filter = [] ){
    $update_token                   = [];

    $this->id_token                 = $this->settings_obj->get_setting( 'id_token' );
    
    $response_arr                   = [];
    $response_arr['code']           = 0;
    $response_arr['alert']          = "";
    $response_arr['data']           = [];

    $endpoint                       = $this->base_url . "job/search/fl=id,job_title,location,created_date,industry,public_description,summary;sort=published_date desc";

    if( $filter && !empty( $filter ) ){

        $search_string = isset( $filter['vj_search'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $filter['vj_search'] ) : "";

        $search_industry = isset( $filter['industry'] ) ? $filter['industry'] : [];
        $search_location = isset( $filter['location'] ) ? $filter['location'] : [];
        $search_function = isset( $filter['function'] ) ? $filter['function'] : [];

        $search_filter_qry = [];
            $search_filter_qry[] = "fq=private_job:0";

        if( $search_industry && !empty( $search_industry ) ){
            $search_filter_qry[] = "fq=sub_industry_id:" . implode( " OR ", $search_industry );
        }

        if( $search_location && !empty( $search_location ) ){
            $search_filter_qry[] = "fq=country_code:" . implode( " OR ", $search_location );
        }

        if( $search_function && !empty( $search_function ) ){
            $search_filter_qry[] = "fq=sfe_id:" . implode( " OR ", $search_function );
        }

        $search_filter_qry_str = implode( "%23&", $search_filter_qry );

        if( !empty( $search_filter_qry_str ) ){
            $endpoint = $endpoint . "?" . $search_filter_qry_str . "%23";
        }

        if( !empty( $search_string ) ){
            $endpoint = $endpoint . "&q=text:" . $search_string . "%23";
        }
```

I am able to get the response on the page required and I am also able to search by location and industry, **however I have the following issue**:

The result includes all results where I am trying to only get jobs that are not private `$search_filter_qry[] = "fq=private_job:0";`

If I edit `$endpoint` and change it to:

```
$endpoint                       = $this->base_url . "job/search/fl=id,job_title,location,created_date,industry,public_description,summary;sort=published_date desc?fq=private_job:0 %23";
```

I get the correct response on the original display of jobs with only results that are public, but then I am unable to perform any searches.

I understand it is because of the concatenation that Is then creating the wrong request when I edit the `$endpoint`and it returns 0 results found.

I have spent a couple of days on this by changing for example `$search_filter_qry[] = "fq=private_job:0";` to `$search_filter_qry[] = "?fq=private_job:0";` by adding in the ?. I will be honest I am not to comfortable yet with the `SOLR Backend` that the `API` uses.

Can anyone please have a fresh look at my code and give me an idea as to what I am missing please.

Comment: Is the `/job/search` part a _direct_ mapping to Solr? or is that endpoint inside your Wordpress installation?

Comment: @MatsLindh Hi, It is direct mapping used by the API.

Comment: My full request to list all jobs that are set to public is as follows: https://domain.vincere.io/api/v2/job/search/fl=id,job_title,location,created_date,industry,public_description,summary;sort=published_date desc?fq=private_job:0%23

Comment: But is `/job/search` the Solr server, or is it your Wordpress installation? If the query is sent directly to a Solr server, the syntax is wrong (i.e. it should be `job/search?fl=..&q=..&fq=...`) Since you're not showing how you're sending the query to the server, it might be that you're also prepending `$endpoint` multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the solution as follows:

I changed the `$endpoint` before the `if` statement to:

```
$endpoint                       = $this->base_url . "job/search/fl=id,job_title,location,created_date,industry,public_description,summary;sort=published_date desc?fq=private_job:0%23";
```

And then after the initial `if statement`,

`if( $filter && !empty( $filter ) ){`

I added the `$endpoint` as

```
$endpoint                       = $this->base_url . "job/search/fl=id,job_title,location,created_date,industry,public_description,summary;sort=published_date desc";
```

This allowed the concatenation to work correctly if the search parameters are not empty.